# How to render a random object from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with a random object in an array, however I am not able to render it

I tried rendering using {planet.name}, and **return (name is not defined):**

```
return (
  <div className="App">
     <div>{planet.name}</div>
     <button onClick={this.renderPlanet}>Next</button>
  </div>
)
```

i tried redering using {planet}, and return **(Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys)):**

```
return (
  <div className="App">
     <div>{planet}</div>
     <button onClick={this.renderPlanet}>Next</button>
  </div>
)
```

App.JS

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    chosenPlanet: 0,
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://swapi.co/api/planets/'

    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          data: response.results,
        })
      })
  }
  render() { 
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.data.length)
    const planet = this.state.data[index]
    console.log(planet)

    return (
      <div className="App">
         <div>{this.planet.name}</div>
        <button onClick={this.renderPlanet}>Next</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

i need to return:

```
<div className="app-container">
   <div>
       <h1>{planet.name}</h1>
       </div>
       <div className="about-container">
         <span>Population: {planet.population}</span>
         <span>Climate: {planet.climate}</span>
         <span>Terrain: {planet.terrain}</span>
         <br />
         <span>Quantidade de Filmes {planet.films.length}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to `console.log(planet)` before render and tell what it looks like?

Comment: How your `planet` looks like ? can you post your console in question ?

Comment: I see you're doing {this.planet.name} in your App.js render . Shouldn't you be doing {planet.name} instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a API call in `componentDidMount` so your data in state will be an empty array initially and you're accessing 0<sup>th</sup> index

```
const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.data.length)
const planet = this.state.data[index]
```

and you end up getting a error `planet is undefined`,

So you can add a check before using value of planet

```
{planet && <div>{planet.name}</div>}
```

You can see a working example in snippet below

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    chosenPlanet: 0,
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://swapi.co/api/planets/'

    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          data: response.results,
        })
      })
  }
  render() { 
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.data.length)
    const planet = this.state.data[index]
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {planet && <div>Name of planet: {planet.name}</div>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/3.0.0/fetch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```